# UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout: How to expand cells to same height?

Tags: swift

I'm trying out the `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` as a way to build a UI where there are both a vertical and horizontal arrangement of cells. ie. one section scrolls vertically and another scrolls horizontally. Something like this:

```
+-------+
|+-----+-----+-----+-----+ 
||  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |
|+-----+-----+-----+-----+ 
||  A  ||
|+-----+|
||  B  ||
|+-----+|
+|  C  |+
 +-----+
 |  D  | 
 +-----+
```

I've built a layout for the horizontal section using this:

```swift
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .estimated(200.0))
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.8), heightDimension: .estimated(200.0))
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
```

This works perfectly except in one aspect. The cells 1, 2, 3 and 4 are all different heights. Which means the display looks more like this:

```
+-------+
|+-----+-----+-----+-----+ 
||  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |
||     +-----+     +-----+ 
|+-----+     |     | 
|            +-----+ 
|+-----+|     
||  A  ||
|+-----+|
||  B  ||
```

The problem I have is that I want all the horizontal cells to have the same height. That height being the height of the largest cell.

Previously I'd done this by manually calculating the height of the tallest cell then setting a constraint on all the cells with that height.

But I'm hoping I don't have to try that here. Is there a way to handle disparate cell heights in a `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` that doesn't resort to manually calculating heights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a working answer but I feel that it's not as good as it could be. Basically I'm manually calculating the height of the tallest cell in the row then setting that as the height of the group. It works, but I feel there should be an option to expand cell dimensions when there is orthogonal scrolling enabling.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has released solution for this in iOS 17. Just use `.uniformAcrossSiblings` height dimension for your item. You can [read more in the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nscollectionlayoutdimension/4173072-uniformacrosssiblings)

For iOS <17 unfortunately we still need to use workarounds.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0), heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0))
let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(0.8), heightDimension: .estimated(200.0))
let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.vertical(layoutSize: groupSize, subitems: [item])
let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
section.orthogonalScrollingBehavior = .continuous
```

When you set your item size as **fractional height 1.0**, you say to use **the same height as the group size**.
So, if you put on the group size an estimate, it will try to use the estimated value but **it will force the other items to use the same height** as the highest item.

I hope it has helped you.

Comment: This seems like a reasonable expectations, but in practice the item size also needs to have the `.estimated(200.0)` height, same as the group, otherwise the item does not resize correctly. Not sure if it should be considered an Apple bug or just how the API is designed.